# How can I avoid competition between overlapping windows in Windows Forms/SlimDX

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, slimdx, direct3d9

I'm creating a Windows Forms application in C# that utilizes the SlimDX(a managed wrapper of the Direct3D API) libraries. Problems arise when I try to take the application fullscreen(a state in which the main window covers the entire desktop area including the taskbar).

The Direct3D device window(main window) displays correctly. The taskbar and other overlapping windows are hidden entirely by the device window. The cursor, however, seems to belong to the window directly beneath the device window. This is evident in the appearance and behavior of the cursor. When I click on the device window focus is changed to the window beneath. This is unexpected behavior for any window.

Also, I am able to click items on the taskbar which will cause a change in focus.

I am changing the window style of the device window to 'TopMost and 'Popup'. Also, I am following the utility class found in the DirectX SDK. When I run a sample from the DX SDK, which uses Win32, this problem doesn't occur. Is it possible that the problem is related to my use of Windows Forms?

There is a lot of code involved in my application so I was hoping for theoretical responses as to why this problem might occur. I found a thread [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/611071-slimdx-winforms-and-full-screen/) that describes a problem when taking device fullscreen, however, the solution is unacceptable. It was suggested to use a 'windowed fullscreen mode'. Instead of modifying the adapter display mode for fullscreen, the device window would simply be resized to cover the entire screen. This solution would prevent the use of adapter formats, resolutions, and refresh rates that are available in fullscreen mode.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the nature of controls found in Windows Forms. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

*A control can be selected and receive input focus if all the following are true: the Selectable value of ControlStyles is set to true, it is contained in another control, and all its parent controls are both visible and enabled.*

The device window in my application belongs to a parent window and the parent window becomes nonvisible once fullscreen is enabled. Its possible that a conflict arose due to the 'focus rules' above. To test the theory I examined the return value from DeviceWindow.Focus()(derives from Control.Focus())...which returned false.

My solution was to create a form used for the sole purpose of fullscreen mode changes. Now, when I want to go fullscreen I reset the device with the handle to the new device window. All problems solved...